# CoreLocation : efficient way to keep track user's location

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

what's the efficient way to keep track user's location? I mean I do not care if the location has been change slightly, because it will waste the resources.

i used in my code: `LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`

to stop every small changes in location...

is there a way to keep track the location only if it oldLocation and newLocation has big different?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are two ways you can achieve that. First way is to use

```
 func startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`  starts the generation of updates based on significant location changes. Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters when you are using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. And if you want to use `startUpdatingLocation` then set `distanceFilter` to distance of your choice and it will report location only if location change is more than distance specified in filter. `distanceFilter` represents the minimum distance (measured in meters) a device must move horizontally before an update event is generated.